# Query object values by key, within an array using Cloud Firestore

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore, non-relational-database

I just started using Cloud Firestore for the CMS side of a web app hosted with the firebase platform. I know this is a very new product, but I have done my due diligence, reviewing all the docs: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/, and SO forums: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore- I can't find an answer, so I was hoping for some simple guidance.

I was wondering if there was a way to just query certain values of an object by key name, stored in an array. I would be using this for an selector element, For example- I have a very long list of stories as an array:

DATA

```
[ {title: "Title One", id: uid1, content: "very long string.."}, {title: "Title Two", id: uid2, content: "very long string.."} ...]
```

ELEMENT

```
<select onchange=fetchStoryByUID(story.val)>
  <option value=story.uid>story.title</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to get just the story titles and uids to append to this element, without having to return all of the object keys and values. The response would be something like:

EXAMPLE QUERY RESPONSE (list of only titles and uids)

```
 [{title: "Title One", id: uid2}, {title: "Title Two", id: uid2} ...]
```

Perhaps I need to re-think my data schema or something, but I feel that this is a common scenario that I didn't see covered in the docs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Right now there is no way to retrieve partial documents using any of the Cloud Firestore mobile SDKs (Android, iOS, or JavaScript).  Some of our server-side SDKs offer a `select()` method which allows you to do this.  It does not affect pricing but it will save bandwidth.

In general you should store data in a document that you intend to fetch all at once.  In your example it may make sense to store the `content` as another document and only fetch it when needed.

Comment: Creating this in normalized tables within a relational db seems straight forward- but what might that `content` look like setup within the FireStore Console? 

Create another collection called `content` under `stories`, and add the document there??